# GAE, GWT and HTTP Session

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

I am building a web application based on Google Application Engine (GAE) and Google Web Toolkit (GWT).

The client (GWT) interacts with the server in the following way:

- asks via RPC (servlet) the URL of an image, selected from a dataset hosted on the server;
- displays the image in the browser;
- stores in a temporary structure the coordinates of the points clicked by the user;
- when the user asks another image, the client sends to the server the user clicks.

Once the server receives the user clicks, it stores them in a database, saving also the user identifier. Since I do not want to use any form of user authentication, I tried to use a HTTP session for distinguishing among different users.

The HTTP session is created in a servlet with the following instructions:

```
public SessionInfo getSessionInfo() {
  HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  if(session.isNew()) session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

  Integer i = (Integer) session.getAttribute("access_count");
  if(i == null) {
    i = new Integer(1);
  } else {
    i = new Integer(i.intValue()+1);
  } // if
  session.setAttribute("access_count", i);  
  SessionInfo sInfo = new SessionInfo(session.getId(), i.intValue());
  return sInfo;
}
```

From the documentation I understood that the following instruction:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
```

would make the session never expire. However, **a new session is created every time the page is refreshed on the browser**. Sessions are enabled.

I have two questions:

- why the refresh causes a new session to be created? Shouldn't the old one be kept?
- Do you have any suggestion on a better way to track users across different uses of the service?

Thanks.

Comment: Are cookies enabled in the browser ?

Comment: Yes. Cookies are are enabled.

Comment: Did you enable sessions? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions

Comment: Yes, session were enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why a new session is created each time, your code looks fine to me. You could try setting the timeout in `web.xml` to see if it makes any difference:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: A reboot solved the problem - I don't know what was misbehaving.